# NuGet, MvvmLight toolkit, is NuGet necessary for all developers?

Tags: nuget, mvvm-light, nuget-package

I have an application for which I've installed NuGet packages for the Mvvm-Light Toolkit, and I've completed and checked in these changes to TFS.  All of the package folders exist in TFS, and the .csproj file references to the GalaSoft libraries are correct, i.e.:

```
<Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\MvvmLightLibs.4.3.31.1\lib\net40\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

However when other developers do a Get Latest, their references to those libraries are not found:

[image]

I don't believe they have used NuGet, but does this matter?  Does each developer have to go through the same NuGet installation of Mvvm-Light to avoid this?

Comment: Do the DLLs exist on their machine or don't they?

Comment: Yes, the dll's are added to the other developer's machines via TFS get latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On TFS you need to check-in the whole solution and not just the project because if you check-in just the project then the dlls will not be checked-in.

You can also get Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f this will allow you to see outside of Visual Studio in your folders if you have checked in the dll or not.

Good luck!

Comment: That's the strange thing, everything was checked in.  I've had the other developer verify that the folders and libraries exist via Windows Explorer, and they are there, and the location of the HintPath in the .csproj file is what it should be.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Well TFS sometimes just doesn't want to listen, have you tried to remove the nugget package checking, and then add the package again and rechecking?

Comment: As a matter of fact, that's exactly what I did and it cleared up.  During development of this particular project, I had several prototypes in source control, and at one point did some consolidating and moving within TFS.  I think this might have been the cause.  Once I removed NuGet packages and then re-installed into the project we're moving forward with, everything fell into place.  Thanks so much for your time and consideration of this question.